# trigger dont update another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to update a second table in that way

I have 2 tables

fr_hikashop_product :
product_id,  product_size_values (varchar(50))

fr_hikashop_product_category :
id (auto increment), 
product_id , 
category_id , 
category_parent_id

and the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_product_size AFTER UPDATE ON fr_hikashop_product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
delete from fr_hikashop_product_category where category_id between 441 and 448 AND product_id = OLD.product_id;
insert ignore into fr_hikashop_product_category (product_id,category_id,category_parent_id) select NEW.product_id,441, 400 from fr_hikashop_product where product_size_values like '%41%' AND product_id = NEW.product_id;
insert ignore into fr_hikashop_product_category (product_id,category_id,category_parent_id) select NEW.product_id,442, 400 from fr_hikashop_product where product_size_values like '%42%' AND product_id = NEW.product_id;
etc ... up to 48
END //
```

let say  product_size_values = '41,43'

nothing happens , no error but I dont get  2 new rows in the table fr_hikashop_product_category

thanks for helping

Comment: yes all works fine if I run a simple query or a procedure

i have tried to add a NEW.product_size_values  but nothing works , it has no effect at all

Comment: The trigger is for UPDATE. If you want it to work for adding new products, you will need to define a trigger for INSERT. You can wrap the trigger logic in a stored procedure and call it from both triggers.

Comment: no the trigger should fire after update on fr_hikashop_product and the only insert into fr_hikashop_product_category
but it is not the problem